# Improper integral of $\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Does the following improper integral converge or diverge
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$$

It seems that the following integral converges but I would like to find $f(x)$ such that $\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx \leq \int\limits_{-1}^{1} f(x) dx$ so it would integrate reasonably and where I could estimate that if the integral of $f(x)$ converges then the first integral converges as well.

Unfortunately I am stuck with finding the following function. If someone could help me that I would be really grateful.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the numerator in terms of convergence or divergence, note that if you ignore the numerator altogether, that the resulting improper integral is still convergent ($\pi$).

Comment: I don't quite get it why is it possible to leave out the numerator and focus on just the improper integral of 1/(sqrt(1-x**2))

Comment: Because the arctangent is bounded between two values (which ones?) so convergence/divergence depends on the nature of the denominator. (in other words, the arctangent in your numerator is a distractor)

Comment: Okay, I understand the point that you are trying to make (because arctan(x) is bounded between -pi/2 and pi/2 and the improper integral of 1/sqrt(1-x**2) converges), but still I am a bit confused how should I write it down in the exam for example. I have not seen such theorem or we have not used it in our problems so far.... 
I am not questioning your answer, it is just bit hard to understand why it works. :(

Comment: $\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{-2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$<$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$<$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the interval into three parts, writing the improper integral as
$$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $$ $$=\int_{-1}^{-1/2} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx+\int_{-1/2}^0 \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx`.$$ The second of the three integrals on the right side above does not present any problems with respect to convergence/divergence. Let us look first at the improper integral $$\int_{-1}^{-1/2} \frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$ The numerator is between arctan(-3) and arctan(-1/2) in the interval (-1,-1/2], so the integral converges iff 
$$\lim_{a \to -1}\int_a^{-1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$
exists. Upon substitution $x=\sin \theta$ the integral becomes $\lim_{a \to -1}(-\pi/6- \text {arcsin}(a))=-\pi/6+\pi/2.$ Now look at the improper integral $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.$$ On the interval [0,1], the numerator is between arctan(2) and arctan(7) so the improper interval converges iff $$\lim_{b \to 1}\int_0^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ exists. Upon substitution $x=\sin \theta$ we see that the limit is $\pi/2.$ Thus the given integral converges.

Answer (score 0):

The problem being at the bounds, consider the Taylor expansions of the integrand
$$\frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=-\frac{\tan ^{-1}(3)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{x+1}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+1} \left(\tan
   ^{-1}(3)-2\right)}{4 \sqrt{2}}+O\left((x+1)^{3/2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\arctan{(5x+2)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{ \tan ^{-1}(7)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-x}}-\frac{ \sqrt{1-x} \left(5 \tan
   ^{-1}(7)-2\right)}{20 \sqrt{2}}+O\left((x-1)^{3/2}\right)$$ So, no problem and the integral will converge.